# System upgrade 13.04 to 13.10 Filesystem check or mount failed

Tags: boot, mount, filesystem

I got started the system upgrade. Unfortunately, my upgrade just froze in the middle of the installation and I, was prompted to force my PC down by pressing the reset button.
Now my Ubuntu won't to start.

I found this:

Run from maintenance shell one line at a time:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
dpkg --configure -a
mount -o remount,ro /
sync
reboot
```

But I don't know where to enter it.

Comment: I fixed my install with just the first 2 commands, then turning computer off and on.

Answer (score 1):

Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> when booting to open up the GRUB menu. Select the *latest version of the kernel* (recovery). **Then** run your commands that are supposed to fix it.

Comment: Once he select "recovery" he should also select "root shell",

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't got encryption, do this:

Boot from a Live USB/CD.
Get all your files out.
Reinstall.

If you have got encryption, it'll be a hell of a lot harder.